# Class keyword in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class

According to [this article](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/js/language/js20-1999-02-18/classes.html) it should be a Javascript 2.0 way to define class. However, I never saw that in practice. Thus the question. How to use class keyword and what is the difference between Javascript 1.x way of doing things?

Comment: The words "February 1999 Draft" in large red letters at the top of the page should be a clue that the article probably doesn't have much relevance to the real world ;-)

Comment: You mean much like HTML 5 draft that is now actually a spec? ;)

Comment: Good point - although HTML5 has been updated more recently :-)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The reason you never saw the `class` keyword used in practice is that [all the current implementations of JavaScript are 1.x.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Versions)

[JavaScript 2.0 was merged into ECMAScript 4 which was rather unpopular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#4th_Edition_.28abandoned.29) and so never made it into the real world.

So to answer your question, how do you use the `class` keyword?  You can't.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
Funny thing though. Visual studio 2008 recognizes it as a valid keyword when writing JavaScript file.

Comment: @Validimir - VS2008 probably recognises the class keyword as you can use it in JScript.NET.

Comment: class (along with lots of other java keywords) is a reserved word so that, theoretically, the language can add support without breaking existing programs. There's a full list at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Reserved_Words.

Comment: You can now use `class` keyword starting ECMA6 (aka ECMA 2015) as mentioned in @AkhilArjun's post below.

Comment: Refer to @AkhilArjun 's answer. I find his answer more useful.

Answer (score 64):

I know this is a old post, but as of today i.e with the advent of **ECMAScript 6** we can declare javascript classes.

The syntax goes as follows :

```
class Person{
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name;
  }
  printName(){
    console.log('Name is '+this.name);
  }
}
var john = new Person('John Doe');
john.printName(); // This prints 'Name is John Doe'
```

A complete guide to this can be found in [this post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in modern JS world that we currently live in.

Answer (score 12):

### Summary

In `ES6` the `class` keyword was introduced. The `class` keyword is no more than syntactic sugar on top of the already existing prototypal inheritance pattern. Classes in javascript is basically another way of writing constructor functions which can be used in order to create new object using the `new` keyword.

### Example

```js
class Person {

  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  talk() { console.log('hi'); }
}

const me = new Person('Willem');

console.log(typeof Person) 
// logs function, Person class is just another constructor function under the hood

console.log(me.__proto__ === Person.prototype) 
// logs true, classes just use the same prototypal inheritance pattern which is used by constructor functions. 
// An object created with the new keyword gets a __proto__ property on it which is a reference to the prototype property on a constructor function.
```

In the above sample there can be observed in the first log that classes create from the `class` keyword actually are functions under the hood.

```
console.log(typeof Person) // logs 'function'
```

`es6` classes use the same prototypal inheritance pattern which is used by constructor functions. Here is another example to demonstrate this behavior:

```js
class Dog {

  constructor (name) {
      this.name = name;
  }
  
  bark () { console.log('bark') };

}

let doggie = new Dog('fluffy');

doggie.bark(); // logs bark


Dog.prototype.bark = () => console.log('woof');  
// changing the prototype of Dog, doggie refers to this with its __proto__ property. 
//Therefore doggie bark method has also changed.


doggie.bark(); // logs woof
```

The takeaway in the above example is that the bark method of any dog instance can be changed at runtime. This is because the bark method of any object created with the Dog class is just referring to this function.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in modern JS world that we currently live in.

Answer (score 5):

You never saw it in practice because virtually nothing supports JavaScript 2.0. That draft is from a specification that died before being anything other than draft.

Answer (score 0):

You can still build classes in JS of course using prototype!

```
var foo = function() {
  this.hurrah = "yay!";
  return this;
}

foo.prototype.doit() {
  alert(this.hurrah);
}
```

Comment: The question specifically asks about the class keyword not how to write a class without the keyword

Answer (score 0):

If you've a Java or C# background, here's how to define a class in JavaScript

```
var MyClass = function (f, l){//constructor 
    //private members
    var firstName = f,
        lastName = l,
        fullName = function () { //fullName is a private function
            return firstName + " " + lastName;
        };
    return {
        //public members
        getFullName: fullName 
    };
}

var output = document.getElementById('Output'); //<div id="Output"></div>
var myName = new MyClass("First", "Last");
output.innerHTML = myName.getFullName();
```

Comment: What you have is not a quite a class, it's just an object. For you to call it a class you have to have a constructor that doesn't return something, and the ability to attach things to its prototype, and there should also be a way to inherit from that class. There's no way to properly inherit from this object because it doesn't have a prototype chain. Note that this approach is not memory friendly because it stores its methods in a closure, instead of on the prototype, it does hide private members which standard JS prototypal class systems don't.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add the ECMA5 way of class making.

Note that it does not have a constructor function this way (but you can trigger an init function if you like)

```
var Class = {
      el: null,
      socket: null,

      init: function (params) {

        if (!(this.el instanceof HTMLElement)) {
          throw new Error('Chat room has no DOM element to attach on.');
        }

        return this.doStuff();

      },
      doStuff: function (params) {
        return this;
      }
};

var instanceofClass = Object.create(Class, {
  el: {
    value: document.body.querySelector('.what ever')
  },
  someMoreData: {
    value: [0,5,7,3]
  }
}).init();
```