# why is class a reserved word in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am planning to implement class inherit interface using JavaScript. `class` is the perfect word as the name of the constructor.

```
class = function (classname) {}; // create a class with classname
classA = new class("classA"); // create a class named classA
```

Unfortunately, `class` is a reserved word in JavaScript.

Why does JavaScript reserve the word `class` (since it never uses it)?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728984/class-keyword-in-javascript

Comment: When "class" doesn't work, you can use nonsensical alternatives like "klass" or "clazz". It's a matter of sticking to a convention.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's reserved to [future-proof ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1.2)

> The following words are used as keywords in proposed extensions and are therefore reserved to allow for the possibility of future adoption of those extensions.

Don't fret though, if you're using best-practices in your JavaScripts, you're placing all accessible functions/variables/constructors in a namespace, which will allow you to use whatever name you'd like:

```
foo = {};
foo['class'] = function(){...code...};
var myClass = new foo['class']();
```

Comment: Note that `Class` is not reserved (capital `C`), and it could be used without problems as the identifier of a variable or function declaration (in fact, is recommended to capitalize the names of constructors). Now, `foo.RESERVEDWORD` will not work on ES3 implementations, since keywords (reserved and future-reserved words) are not allowed in the grammar of the dot property accessor, nor in the object literal syntax (BTW, that's why in JSON format, keys must be quoted...). This changes on ES5, now is possible to access any valid identifier name, even if it's reserved, e.g. `({if:1}).if == 1;`

Comment: Here's a direct link to "*7.6.1.2 Future Reserved Words*" in the HTML version of the spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1.2

Answer (score 9):

Languages evolve. It is prudent to reserve a few keywords that might come in use later. [According to the ECMA standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255/reserved-keywords-in-javascript), `class` is a Future Reserved Word.

If you did not reserve them, introducing new keywords could conflict with existing code (which already might be using the word for other things). Happened with Java and `assert`.

Comment: Very true about the evolution! We can now use class keyword in javascript code starting ECMA6 (aka ECMA 2015) as mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

Answer (score 7):

Now it's used in [ECMAScript® 2015 Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/):

```
class Foo {
    constructor(bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
new Foo(10).bar; // 10
```

Answer (score 4):

`class` is reserved as a future keyword by the ECMAScript specification

[Reserved Words - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words)

Answer (score 2):

It is there so that support can be added in future without breaking existing programs. Please take a look at the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728984/class-keyword-in-javascript).

You can also look at

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words