# DHTML, multiple CSS Classes, in IE7

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-7, dhtml

In IE 7, my sample static HTML and CSS correctly result in a horizontal and spaced set of div tags:

[JSFiddle, Sample #1](http://jsfiddle.net/Mystagogue/nk5Wx/)

But as soon as IE7 is asked to the same thing, with javascript modifying the "class" of the elements, it completely loses horizontal formatting:

[JSFiddle, Sample #2](http://jsfiddle.net/XjuFP/3/)

This second example generates the HTML, and updates it with a timer, but it is identical HTML.

I speculate this has something to do with having more than one class associated with the div elements (class="count-digit digit4"), and the fact that I'm updating the second of those two classes dynamically.  I figure IE7 just gives up.  Is that the real issue?  And regardless, what would be the proper way to fix this - so that dynamic updates work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `element.setAttribute("className", "your-classname-here");`  "Class" is a reserved word in ECMAscript, so they had to go with "className" instead (I'm guessing).

There's more info on SO here: [why is class a reserved word in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524618/why-is-class-a-reserved-word-in-javascript)

Comment: OMG and I knew that too!  DOH!  Yup, that fixed it.