# .id vs .className on returning boolean values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, dom

I am trying to get a webelement's id and class if it has one. The first check using the id works fine, but the one checking the class doesn't. I don't know why but ' id '  returns true but ' class ' does not return anything. Any ideas on why this doesn't work and how to make it work?

```
 var id = currentElement.id;
      if(id)
      {
        targetDocument.write(" id=\""+currentElement.id+"\"");
      }
   var class = currentElement.className;
      if(class)
      {
        targetDocument.write(" class=\""+currentElement.className+"\"");
      }
```

Comment: `class` is a reserved word... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524618/why-is-class-a-reserved-word-in-javascript

Comment: Open your browser's developer console. This should be the first thing you do when troubleshooting code.

Comment: sorry. I'm super new to this. Thanks remyabel now I know. dystroy, this is just a snippet and it does compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, `class` is a reserved word. try `className` (for example) instead.