# selection using tag + text +class

Tags: jquery

Please refer to me a reference or documentation that explain these kind of selection using tag, text and class.

```
var button_var = $('<button/>',
       {
           text: 'Click',
           class: 'btn_class'

       });
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this reference for the specific jQuery method: http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes

That is not a selection. That is creating a `<button>` DOM element with properties specified by the anonymous object passed as the second parameter.

Note: until the object is added to the DOM somewhere it is a disconnected element.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/zr9tdLv1/

A cut & paste of the resulting  DOM element (from Chrome DOM inspector is)

```
<button class="btn_class">Click</button>
```

**Update: (thanks to mention by @Don P)**

As `class` [is to become a reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords), you should quote the key name. e.g.

```
'class': 'btn_class'
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/zr9tdLv1/1/

Comment: I do not believe you can use class in all browers as you have it, you would have to pass the key as a string.

Comment: @Don P: Unless there are special characters in the name the "key" does not have to be quoted.

Comment: Do I must use <button/> tag ? I tried <button> and it give same effect.

Comment: but we create the button like this <button></button> !!?

Comment: You can use any of those 3 formats. It is smart enough to figure out what you are creating. The self-closing syntax is the simplest shortest "correct" one if you are not adding child elements.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie please reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524618/why-is-class-a-reserved-word-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

It's just creating the element button with html attributes and you'll be able to see the final result like below:

```
<button class="btn_class">Click</button>
```

So, by the way you can create the element with the attributes (HTML DOM Properties) all html have like id, data-* attributes. You can also have `html` as attribute and use there html like `html: '<div>foo</div>'`

---

Thanks to @TrueBlueAussie, found the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes)

Comment: thanks, no documentation explain creating element in more detail ? like other options for example ?

Comment: I see thanks, it is first time I see code like this so I am trying to understand. Why <button/> is used not "<button>" or input[type='button'] ?

Comment: It's the way we do to create the element `<button></button>` that is just a short hand...

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are trying to achieve this

```
$("button.btn_class[value='Click']")
```