# What is the difference between class and classname in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In order to find children objects of a certain class name, I had to create my own helper function

```
findChildrenByTagName = function(obj, name){
    var ret = [];
    for (var k in obj.children){
        if (obj.children[k].className === name){
            ret.push(obj.children[k]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

An example of how it works is

```
var li = document.createElement('li');
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('class','answer_input');
li.appendChild(input);
console.log(findChildrenByTagName(li,"answer_input"));
```

However when I replace className above by class in the function above, the code doesn't work. So I am naturally wondering what the difference is between class and className. A quick search on google doesn't reveal anything.

Also what's the best way to return a list of children of a particular class name for a generic object? If such doesn't exist, is there a way to add a method to all objects so that I can call

```
li.findChildrenByTagName("answer_input");
```

instead of the global function above?

Comment: Because "class" is a reserved word in JavaScript, the name of the corresponding property for the "class" attribute is `className`. This applies only if you are accessing it as an object property.

Comment: Thanks BatScream. Can you give some examples to illustrate waht you mean by "name of the corresponding property" versus "attribute"?

Comment: When you use `input.setAttribute("class",value)`, it won't be a problem because here you are not accessing the javascript keyword. But when you try to access it as a property of an javascript object as in `children[k].class`, that becomes invalid.

Comment: Thanks! Credit goes to both you and answer below.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Let's break this into answerable parts:

### Question 1:

> What is the difference between class and classname in javascript?

Your title question.

### Answer 1:

Class is an attribute in an html element `<span class='classy'></span>`

While, on the other hand, `.className` is a property that can by called on an element to get/set its class.

```
var element = document.createElement('span');
element.className = 'classy'
// element is <span class='classy'></span>
```

Setting the class can also be accomplished with `.getAttribute('class')` and `.setAttribute('class', 'classy')`. We change manipulate classes so often, however, that it merited its own `.className` method.

---

### Question 2:

> However when I replace className above by class in the function above, the code doesn't work. So I am naturally wondering what the difference is between class and className.

### Answer 2: element.class is not a property.

Class may be an attribute of an element, but you can't call it like `el.class`. The way you do it is by `el.className`, **like you already figured out**. If you look at the [MDN for Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className), you'll see that elements have many properties and methods, but `.class` isn't one.

[image]

---

### Question 3:

> Also what's the best way to return a list of children of a particular class name for a generic object?

### Answer 3: Use .getElementsByClassName

Rather than using a purpose-made function, people frequently "chain" methods one-after-another to achieve your desired effect.

Based on your needs, I think you're asking for the `.getElementsByClassName` method. Here are the [full docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByClassName) and an excerpt:

> The Element.getElementsByClassName() method returns returns a live HTMLCollection [array] containing all child elements which have all of the given class names.

To reuse the example from your answer:

```
var li = document.createElement('li');
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('class','answer_input');
li.appendChild(input);
console.log(li.getElementsByClassName("answer_input")[0]);
// would return the <input class='answer_input'> as the first element of the HTML array
```

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful and comprehensive explanations! I often found getElementsByTagName when I search for select child elements by class name.

Answer (score 2):

Don't get confused between the reserved word 'class' and 'className' attribute of DOM element.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className):

> *The name **className** is used for this property instead of class because of conflicts with the "**class**" keyword in many languages which are used to manipulate the DOM.*

**EDIT:**
The 'class' [word used on js 1.0 but in js 2.0 was merged with ECMAScript 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728984/class-keyword-in-javascript) which was rather unpopular and depreciated. but it is still a reserved word.

Comment: ['class' **is** a reserved word in JS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7524648/497418).

Answer (score 0):

The general concept is that class is an object and `className` is "one" of its properties. Refer to the links on how to use the `class` attribute for manipulation. Kindly correct me if my perception/understanding is wrong.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_classname.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp