# why class is not considered as a property of HTMLElement

Tags: html, dom

I'm new to html/html5, just a question on properties of HTMLElement.

For example, `HTMLInputElement` has properties such as `name`, `type`, `value`, so I thought every available attributes is properties for an element, and of course class attribute should be a property since we can write:

```
<input class="XXX" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

but according to the link from MDN below, `class` is not a property for `HTMLInputElement`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement

we can see that `class` is not in the properties list.

So what kind of attributes can be considered as `properties`?

Comment: Because of compatibility to ECMAScript 3, where `class` was a (future) reserved word which couldn’t be a property name (it’s `className` instead). Same reason a `<label>`’s `for` attribute has the corresponding `htmlFor` property. See [What is the difference between `class` and `className` in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27752441/4642212). `className` is still not on the `HTMLInputElement` prototype, because it’s on the more general [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) prototype from which `HTMLInputElement` inherits.

Answer (score 1):

The MDN page for [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) page has a section `inheritance`, which shows it as inheriting from `HTMLElement` which itself inherits from `Element` (and then `Node`, etc):

> [image: inheritance]

Everything defined at the more abstract levels is available in the more concrete levels, and interface `Element` defines a property [**`className`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) which looks to be what you are after.

There is also the related property [**`classList`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) which in many cases is just as usable if not more.