# Why is "this" in an ES6 class not implicit?

Tags: javascript, java, ecmascript-6, this

I know that ES6 solved a lot of problems that existed with the `this` keyword in ES5, such as arrow functions and classes.

My question relates to the usage of `this` in the context of an ES6 class and why it has to be written explicitly. I was originally a Java developer and I come from a world where the following lines of code were perfectly natural.

```
class Person {
  private String myName;

  public Person() { 
    myName = "Heisenberg";
  }

  public void sayMyName() {
    System.out.println("My name is " + myName);
  }
}
```

The compiler will always refer to the value of the field `myName`, unless it has a local variable with the name `myName` defined in the scope of the method.

However, once we convert this code to ES6:

```
class Person {

  constructor() {
    this.myName = "Heisenberg";
  }

  sayMyName() {
    console.log(`My name is ${myName}`);
  }
}
```

This won't work and it will throw an `Uncaught ReferenceError: myName is not defined`. The only way to fix this is to throw in an explicit `this` reference:

```
console.log(`My name is ${this.myName}`)
```

I understand the need for `this` in the constructor since ES6 classes don't allow your fields to be defined outside of the constructor, but I don't understand why the Javascript engines can't (or won't, because of the standard) do the same as Java compilers can in the case of `sayMyName`

Comment: So you basically are asking why two mostly completely different languages behave differently? Note that the "java" in "javascript" has nothing to do with the programming language Java.

Comment: @luk2302 - If you said the languages have basically no relationship, that's true.  But when you say "the 'java' in 'javascript' has nothing to do with the programming language Java", that's false as you could verify with a quick google search.  From wikipedia: "... **upon receiving a trademark license from Sun**, the name JavaScript was adopted. **This was somewhat of a marketing move at the time, with Java being very popular around then**"

Comment: Not only are you comparing different languages but also different concepts. _"I understand the need for this in the constructor"_ Why should the constructor function be handled differently?

Comment: It would make the language inconsistent and more complex since now we would need some other construct to refer to variables in outer scopes (instead of members). However, questions about design decisions  for the language are not a good fit for SO in general. You might want to ask on https://esdiscuss.org instead.

Comment: @FelixKling I guess your comment is a better answer than the current one, if you post an answer I'll be happy to accept it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe I will not directly answer your question, but I'll try to direct the way you should think about JS `class` keyword.

Under the cover there is no magic about it. Basically it's a syntatic sugar over prototypal inheritance that was since the beginning of JavaScript.

To read more about classes in JS click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728984/class-keyword-in-javascript).

As of why you need explicitly write `this` is that because in JS it's always context sensitive, so you should refer to exact object. Read [more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).