# How can I access a class as "this" when adding event listeners, using bind?

Tags: javascript

I have an eventlistener that looks like this:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', scroll.throttle(
    triggered, 
    {state: state, wrapper: wrapper, children: children, scroll: scroll},
    50
));
```

And I have a class that looks like this:

```
Scroll = class{
    constructor(){
        this.on = true; 
    }
    throttle(fn, v, wait){
        var time = Date.now();
        return () => {
            if ((time + wait - Date.now()) < 0 && this.on) {
                fn(v);
                time = Date.now();
            }
        }
    }
    triggered(o){
        if(o.state.check  !== 0){
            o.scroll.on = false;
            o.wrapper.classList.toggle('flic-down', o.state.check === 1)
            o.wrapper.classList.toggle('flic-up', o.state.check === -1)
            o.state.update();

            o.wrapper.classList.add('flic-transition')
            setTimeout(()=>{this.changeDone(o)}, 1200);
        }
    }
    changeDone(o) {
        o.wrapper.classList.remove('flic-transition', 'flic-up', 'flic-down');
        o.children.setClasses(o.state.state);
        o.wrapper.getElementsByClassName('flic-active')[0].scrollIntoView(true);
        o.scroll.on = true;
    }
},
```

I don't like passing state, wrapper, children and scroll as variables. I would prefer to store them in the class when instantiating them. I understand the problem is that "this" won't be passed correctly and that it can be bound. But because the throttle function I don't understand how to pass this.

Comment: Just a question: Is this valid JavaScript? If so, I'm all ears! I didn't realize you could use this kind of syntax

Comment: @ControlAltDel What makes you think it isn't?

Comment: I don't see any issue with `this` - you're using arrow functions everywhere already. Have you just tried to make them instance properties?

Comment: What is `triggered`, and why does your `throttle` function take `v` as an argument?

Comment: @Bergi if i console.log(this) in triggered, it's undefined.

Comment: @Bergi It seems to be a function that calls another function dynamically.

Comment: @Bergi Triggered is the actual code that is throttled, maybe it should have a new name. V is all the variables I want to pass to triggered.

Comment: @Bergi this Q/A on SO goes to why I am confused. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728984/class-keyword-in-javascript. It claims that this functionality was part of JavaScript 2.0, which never rolled out. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Would changing your method classes like `throttle(fn, v, wait){}` into an arrow method class function help? `throttle = (fn, v, wait) => {}`. Might keep the context of `this` if you change all your method classes to arrows.

Comment: @ControlAltDel sure you can! (but only in edge not IE11) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: @ReyHaynes you can't do that in classes. Also it's not throttle() that is the problem, it's triggered(). Maybe I have to bind in several instances, i've tried binding to the event listener and the function that throttle responds with etc.

Comment: @Himmators I use arrow method classes all the time.

Comment: ...and if `throttle` isnt the issue...also try `fn.bind(this, v)` within throttle.

Comment: @ControlAltDel You might want to read the second answer to the post you linked. `class` syntax is official since 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to separate the throttling from the scrolling.

```
class Throttle {
    constructor() {
        this.on = true; 
    }
    get(fn, wait) {
        var time = Date.now();
        return (...args) => {
            if ((time + wait - Date.now()) < 0 && this.on) {
                fn(...args);
                time = Date.now();
            }
        }
    }
}

class Scroll {
    constructor(state, wrapper, children) {
        this.state = state;
        this.wrapper = wrapper;
        this.children = children;
        this.throttle = new Throttle();
    }
    triggered() {
        if (this.state.check !== 0) {
            this.throttle.on = false;
            this.wrapper.classList.toggle('flic-down', this.state.check === 1)
            this.wrapper.classList.toggle('flic-up', this.state.check === -1)
            this.state.update();

            this.wrapper.classList.add('flic-transition')
            setTimeout(()=>{this.changeDone()}, 1200);
        }
    }
    changeDone() {
        this.wrapper.classList.remove('flic-transition', 'flic-up', 'flic-down');
        this.children.setClasses(this.state.state);
        this.wrapper.getElementsByClassName('flic-active')[0].scrollIntoView(true);
        this.throttle.on = true;
    }
}
```

You then would do

```
const scroll = new Scroll(state, wrapper, children);
window.addEventListener('scroll', scroll.throttle.get(() => scroll.triggered(), 50));
```

Notice the arrow function being passed to `throttle.get` that calls `triggered` on the `scroll` instance, instead of passing the method without a context.

---

If you want to mix them both in the same class, I don't see why `throttle` would take a `fn` and `v` as parameters. You're only using it to call `triggered` anyway:

```
class ThrottledScroll {
    constructor(state, wrapper, children) {
        this.state = state;
        this.wrapper = wrapper;
        this.children = children;
        this.throttle = new Throttle();
        this.on = true; 
    }
    get(wait) {
        var time = Date.now();
        return () => {
            if ((time + wait - Date.now()) < 0 && this.on) {
                this.triggered();
                time = Date.now();
            }
        }
    }
    triggered() {
        if (this.state.check !== 0) {
            this.on = false;
            this.wrapper.classList.toggle('flic-down', this.state.check === 1)
            this.wrapper.classList.toggle('flic-up', this.state.check === -1)
            this.state.update();

            this.wrapper.classList.add('flic-transition')
            setTimeout(()=>{this.changeDone()}, 1200);
        }
    }
    changeDone() {
        this.wrapper.classList.remove('flic-transition', 'flic-up', 'flic-down');
        this.children.setClasses(this.state.state);
        this.wrapper.getElementsByClassName('flic-active')[0].scrollIntoView(true);
        this.on = true;
    }
}
```

with

```
const scroll = new ThrottledScroll(state, wrapper, children);
window.addEventListener('scroll', scroll.get(50));
```

Comment: The thing is that it's in the callback, changeDone that throttle.on is set to true again

Comment: @Himmators Sure, what's the problem with that?

Comment: Ah, ok, I see what you did now, that makes sense, will try it!

Answer (score 0):

In your class constructor, you can bind your class methods' context to the class with `this.methodName = this.methodName.bind(this)`. ReyHaynes is right, this can also be accomplished by defining class methods as arrow functions, but I believe that's still an uncomfirmed ES7 feature, so you might not want to use that.

If that's unclear or unhelpful, you might find some helpful context [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56). It's a React resource, but, if I understand correctly, your problem is one dealt with in React all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the bind to the constructor worked for the class, that handles the binding issue when called out of context:

```
Scroll = class{
    constructor(){
        this.on = true; 
        this.triggered = this.triggered.bind(this)
        this.changeDone = this.changeDone.bind(this)
    }
    throttle(fn, v, wait){
        var time = Date.now();
        return () => {
            if ((time + wait - Date.now()) < 0 && this.on) {
                fn(v);
                time = Date.now();
            }
        }
    }
    triggered(o){
        if(o.state.check  !== 0){
            o.scroll.on = false;
            o.wrapper.classList.toggle('flic-down', o.state.check === 1)
            o.wrapper.classList.toggle('flic-up', o.state.check === -1)
            o.state.update();

            o.wrapper.classList.add('flic-transition')
            setTimeout(()=>{this.changeDone(o)}, 1200);
        }
    }
    changeDone(o) {
        o.wrapper.classList.remove('flic-transition', 'flic-up', 'flic-down');
        o.children.setClasses(o.state.state);
        o.wrapper.getElementsByClassName('flic-active')[0].scrollIntoView(true);
        o.scroll.on = true;
    }
}
```

The event listener needed to have `scroll.triggered` vs `triggered` unless you deconstructed (`const { triggered } = scroll`) before it and we didn't see that:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', scroll.throttle(
    scroll.triggered, 
    {state: state, wrapper: wrapper, children: children, scroll: scroll},
    50
))
```